# Select the array with the least distance value from array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with some data including distance.

The array looks like this:

```
$arr = array
(
    0 => array
        (
            'distance' => 0.00037306794379581,
            'city' => 'a'
        ),

    1 => array
        (
            'distance' => 0.00070784665463427,
            'city' => 'b'
        ),

    2 => array
        (
            'distance' => 0.0033977868300665,
            'city' => 'c'
        ),

    3 => array
        (
            'distance' => 0.012137901860616,
            'city' => 'd'
        ),

);
```

I want to get the array with the least `distance`, In this case it should be the first one

`0 => array
        (
            'distance' => 0.00037306794379581,
            'city' => 'a'
        )`

I can get the least distance from the whole array using:

```
$min = array_reduce($arr, function($min, $details) {
  return min($min, $details['distance']);
}, PHP_INT_MAX);
```

But how to get the array with that min distance

`0 => array
        (
            'distance' => 0.00037306794379581,
            'city' => 'a'
        )` ?

Or at least get the city with that min distance

Answer (score 0):

You could sort by distance ascending, and then take the first element.

```
<?php

$array =
[
    [
        'distance' => 3,
        'city' => 'Leeds'
    ],
    [
        'distance' => 1,
        'city' => 'Manchester'
    ],
    [
        'distance' => 2,
        'city' => 'Chichester'
    ]
];

array_multisort(array_column($array, 'distance'), $array);
var_dump($array[0]);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
    ["distance"]=>
    int(1)
    ["city"]=>
    string(10) "Manchester"
  }
```